# playorm launches exception when my mapped classes are in a separate jar file

Tags: playorm

When I run my playOrm junit test in the same project I have the nosql.Persistence class (and therefore my mapped entities) it runs fine. 
However, I need to package my entities on a jar file, with my DAO and my find methods.
When I use this dao from other project, I get the exception bellow.

Have no clue. Any thoughts about where to start looking for?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained exception)=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:44)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:51)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:53)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:48)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:41)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:40)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.getEntityManager(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:46)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.AbstractDao.getEm(AbstractDao.java:10)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.UserDao.insertOrUpdateUser(UserDao.java:15)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.module.UserModule.persistData(UserModule.java:101)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.mapred.SelectorReducer.reduce(SelectorReducer.java:55)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.mapred.SelectorReducer.reduce(SelectorReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle.<init>(MetaClassSingle.java:22)
  while locating com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaInfo.findOrCreate(MetaInfo.java:60)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:57)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaAbstractClass.<init>(MetaAbstractClass.java:17)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle.<init>(MetaClassSingle.java:22)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle$$FastClassByGuice$$29abb300.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.TypedRow_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta.testInstanceCreation(DboTableMeta.java:93)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta.<clinit>(DboTableMeta.java:84)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run into some kind of classloading issue.  You may need to pass in a classloader when you create the NoSqlEntityManagerFactory.  You are dealing with this code here

```
static {
    ProxyFactory f = new ProxyFactory();
    f.setSuperclass(TypedRow.class);
    f.setInterfaces(new Class[] {NoSqlTypedRowProxy.class});
    f.setFilter(new MethodFilter() {
        public boolean isHandled(Method m) {
            // ignore finalize()
            if(m.getName().equals("finalize"))
                return false;
            else if(m.getName().equals("equals"))
                return false;
            else if(m.getName().equals("hashCode"))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    });
    Class clazz = f.createClass();
    testInstanceCreation(clazz);

    typedRowProxyClass = clazz;

    NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*");
}

private static Proxy testInstanceCreation(Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
        Proxy inst = (Proxy) clazz.newInstance();
        return inst;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create proxy for type="+clazz, e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create proxy for type="+clazz, e);
    }
}
```

NOTICE it is in a static initializer block so will run once and this code always works when in the normal case.  For instance, if you have a Car class that gets created in one ClassLoader, and the same Car class is created in another classloader, you can actually cast  like so  (Car)car and get a classCastException becuase the car which is a Car in one classloader is not the Car of the other classloader.

Okay, so step 1 is to try passing in your own classloader when you create the NoSqlEntityManagerFactory so then you know which classloader is being used.  Looking at my code above, I am not sure which classloader is creating the proxy yet so I need to check on that to make sure it is the same classloader.

ONE big question is whether hadoop is already using a javassist that was loaded in another classloader or did you send a javassist as part of the mapreduce job?

EDIT: Okay, ALSO, you need to set the thread Context Loader for javassist as well....I will fix this in PlayOrm so on next release you won't have to....for now do this

1. Call Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(yourClassloader)
2. Call Bootstrap.create passing it the SAME classloader as well
3. verify javassist is loaded from that same classloader

Here is the code where I found the infomation on which classloader javassist is using for your reference

```
   protected ClassLoader getClassLoader0() {
591         ClassLoader loader = null;
592         if (superClass != null && !superClass.getName().equals("java.lang.Object"))
593             loader = superClass.getClassLoader();
594         else if (interfaces != null && interfaces.length > 0)
595             loader = interfaces[0].getClassLoader();
596  
597         if (loader == null) {
598             loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
599             // In case javassist is in the endorsed dir
600             if (loader == null) {
601                 loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
602                 if (loader == null)
603                     loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
604             }
605         }
606 
607         return loader;
608     }
```

Dean

Comment: The classloader problem was being generated by a jar conflict. javassist version 3.16.1 worked fine.